# Custom [Authorize] filter for Ajax Jquery requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, asp.net-authorization, jquery-ajaxq

I have derived from AuthorizeAttribute class and made my own CustomAuthorize

```
  protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {

                Data = new DataSourceResult { Errors = new { error = "NotAuthorized" } }
                ,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
          // this is a standard request, let parent filter to handle it
           base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

There are so many places where I am using Ajax Jquery call and it does not look practical to check response in each one of those and then do

```
window.location.href='/Auth/login';
```

I am just wondering , Can we redirect to login page from HandleUnauthorizedRequest method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a base controller on which you place your custom authorize attribute.
Something like:

```
[YourAuthorizeAttribute]
public class BaseAuthorizeController : BaseController
{
    public BaseAuthorizeController() {}
}
```

The above will be applied to all of your actions, not just the ajax actions.
You could expand the attribute by passing it a boolean of false for actions that do not need the new logic;

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly bool authorize = true;public YourAuthorizeAttribute(bool authorize = true)
    {
        this.authorize = authorize;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!authorize)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Your custom authentication logic
    }
```

Comment: Can't add a base controller now as this would require a massive refactoring. Is there any other solution? Can't this be redirected from HandleUnauthorizedRequest method?